# How to show unselected language switcher

Tags: magento-1.9, language, switcher

Please, I need your help to solve this. If we have 2 view English and french.

So if visitor open example.com/en will show in header English language as text so what i need is if visitor open example.com/en will show french as text.

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language top-select">
    <select id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Your Language') ?>" onchange="window.location.href=this.value" style="width:auto;">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>" <?php if($lang_flag): ?> data-image="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flags/'.$_lang->getCode().'.png'); ?>" <?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $("#select-language").selectbox();
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the inline translations to "switch" the translations for the english and french store view.

Here is a tutorial on inline translations
http://inchoo.net/magento/inline-translation-in-magento/

So you would basically translate in your english store view and put in the french string and the other way around in your french store view

Comment: No you miss my point i need change the default word in the english store show english and if i hover it by the mouse show list to choose the view. and same with french view must show another view.